# How to detect character in natural text image?

Tags: opencv, character, vision

I have a project about Character Recognition (using openCV libraries).
I don't know how to detect character in text image. 
Can you recommend some methods to do this?
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/) is a tutorial, it is dated and uses the C-style API though. [This](http://image2measure.net/files/Mastering_OpenCV.pdf) online book has a bunch related to OCR using OpenCV in chapter 5. Many people have done work intergrating [tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) (an OCR engine) with OpenCV, so you might want to check that out.